# semantic-complete-jump-local returns "No Match" in Emacs

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-semantic

I'm running Emacs 23.3.1 with CEDET 1.1.
The command `semantic-complete-jump-local` always returns `"No Match"` while `semantic-complete-jump` works fine.

I looked into the `semantic-complete.el` but my knowledge of elisp is not good enough to understand what's happening...

Comment: Try running semantic-analyze-current-context and then semantic-complete-jump-local. It's possible the problem is that what you're trying to jump to, is not local to the current buffer. If that's the case then semantic-complete-jump is the one you should call.

Comment: Do you still see the same problem? @xmonk I followed your guidance, and am still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I'm no longer running Emacs 23.3.1 I'm running 24.3.50.1 with CEDET version 2.0, and I don't have that issue. In what programming language are you seeing the issue? It's possible that support for that language is incomplete or lacking in your version.

Comment: Use `helm-semantic` instead. It's probably better anyway.

Comment: @xmonk happens with C, C++, and Python. Haven't tried anything else.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is wrong with just using `semantic-complete-jump`?

Comment: @PythonNut Nothing wrong with it per se, but if the functionality for a local jump is offered by `semantic`, you should be able to use it if you want to.